# React or Web design flow for Payment plans for an e-commerce site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

Are there any designs are code samples for a flow. Where an e-commerce website owner wants to allow their customers to pay over time for products or services, like a payment plan. I would like to have some React code examples if possible or generic websites are good also.